# How to combine multiple GeometryGroup objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

I have 2 different `GeometryGroup` collections that I want to composite, but couldn't find anything on the net for this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the `Children` of one collection into the other, or build a third, new `GeometryGroup` which does a union of both children.  For example:

```
GeometryGroup newGroup = new GeometryGroup();
foreach(var child in group1.Children.Union(group2.Children)) 
   newGroup.Children.Add(child);
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, is this the only way? Because in my loop, I just modify the contents of these both collections to change their positions, etc. If I combine them at each instance then I have to create a new GeometryGroup for each frame of my app (30 fps) with 200 shapes total. I imagine this would be a big overhead right? Maybe I should use 2 canvas controls?

Comment: Thanks Reed, in that case, is there a means to specify the composition? I am not sure how to combine the results of multiple canvas controls.

Comment: @Joan: You can just put them both in a grid, in the same row/column, and they'll "overlap" perfectly.  By default, they're transparent backgrounds, so it should just work.  The only issue will be z ordering - you'll have to do z ordering on a canvas by canvas level, so if you have overlappings paths, one canvas's contents will always be "on top" of the other's.

Comment: Thanks Reed, can I make a grid with 1x1 cell?

Comment: @Joan: Yes - by default, Grid as 1x1 cells.  Just put both canvas controls inside the Grid, and that's what you'll get ;)

Comment: Thanks Reed, btw in that case I imagine you don't even need to specify  the column and row for the canvas controls right? I am not sure if the controls themselves know which column and row to use in that case.

Comment: @Joan: Nope - by default they'll be put in row 0 and col 0.  You only need to set the attached props (Grid.Row/Column) if you want them somewhere else (though I often still set them to be explicit)